# Service seems to ignore passed variables when it's started

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Service, where I pass in `minDistanceFilter` as extras.

```
    class LocationService : Service() {
    
        private var minDistanceMeters: Float = 0.00001f
    
        override fun onStart(intent: Intent?, startId: Int) {
            super.onStart(intent, startId)
            val extras = intent!!.extras
            minDistanceMeters = extras!!["minDistanceFilter"] as Float
        }
    }
```

This is how I start the service, and pass in the `minDistanceFilter` as extras parameter.

```
fun startLocationUpdates() {
        serviceIntent = Intent(this, locationService.javaClass)
        serviceIntent.putExtra("minDistanceFilter", minDistanceFilter);
        if (!Util.isBackgroundServiceRunning(locationService.javaClass, this)) {
            startService(serviceIntent)
            // After starting the service, we register the ServiceBroadcast as well
            // to get the results back.
            val inf = IntentFilter()
            inf.addAction(LocationService.ActionTag)
            registerReceiver(sb, inf)
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.service_start_successfully), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.service_already_running), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

However when the service gets started in the background, I can see that `minDistanceMeters` is still set to the default value of 0.00001f, instead of what has been passed in previously. What am I missing please?

UPDATE:
This is my onStartCommand:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        return START_STICKY
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
         val extras = intent!!.extras
         val item = extras.getFloat("minDistanceFilter")
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags,startId)
    }
```

UPDATE:
Use this:
`val item = extras.getFloat("minDistanceFilter")`

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with my `onStartCommand`, which return `START_STICKY `.  I still used your and it doesn't work. Same behaviour as with `onStart`.

Comment: updated answer, thy it